# Finding Values of same ID from different table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables:
1.Users (This table contains all the information of users like name, Userid, mobileno)
2.Transaction (This table contains the information of all the transaction of a user)

But the UserID is same in both the tables

I have some filter conditions like:
[ TransactionType=1 AND status=1 and (RealCash>0 or Bonus>0 or Winning>0)] 
which i want to apply on Transaction table

once I applied the condition i will have some UserID

Now i want that the information of the users from the Users table that have the same UserID which i've obtained from above from the transaction table

How can i do that in MYSQL ?

Comment: it is called JOIN

Comment: can you help me with the query ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use JOIN : https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

For example:

```
SELECT 
    u.name, 
    u.Userid, 
    u.mobileno, 
    t.TransactionType
FROM
    Users u
INNER JOIN Transaction t ON t.Userid = c.Userid
WHERE t.TransactionType=1 AND t.status=1 and (t.RealCash>0 or t.Bonus>0 or t.Winning>0)
```

But read carefully about other join types (left, right, cross) as you may get different results.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
name, Userid, mobileno
FROM
Users
WHERE
UserID IN (SELECT
UserID
FROM
Transaction
WHERE
TransactionType=1 AND status=1 and (RealCash>0 or Bonus>0 or Winning>0);